# In Quorum, is it possible to replicate a private smart contract to a new node after the contract is deployed?

Tags: quorum

This question is about Quorum. I noticed that the `quorum` tag is present on this site hence adding the question here. If this question should rather be asked elsewhere, please let me know.

I am exploring Quorum for a business use case. I have this peculiar situation where there is a private contract `Contract X` shared between `Node A` and `Node B`. A new node `Node C` joins the network. `Node C` needs to have access to the private contract `Contract X` which is already deployed on `Node A` and `Node B`.

Is there any way to get `Contract X` along with its current state on `Node C`?

I know that if I have access to the source code or ABI of `Contract X`, I can just deploy `Contract X` on `Node C`. However, as per my understanding, this will give `Contract X` on `Node C` a different address than what it has on the other nodes. So any transaction I send to all three nodes targeting `Contract X` with fail on `Node C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/552

Quorum v2.1 currently does not support this -- a private contract shared on A and B cannot be extended to node C -- we have a solution that we are working on but this is still pretty early in the pipeline.

Our recommendation for when you need to add participants is to create a new contract Z with A, B, and C nodes, move the data over through a private txn on that contract, and then finally kill the original X.